# What are the consequences if a contrast is non-orthogonal?

Tags: intuition, contrasts

Everywhere I read about orthogonal contrasts.  I know what they are, but I see nowhere why it matters if they are orthogonal or not.  What are the consequences?

Answer (score 3):

Orthogonality guarantees that values can change along one axis without changing on the others. That’s not true of non-orthogonal axes. In the case of your contrast, this makes me think that you would thus mix the effects of your predictors making your model harder to fit and interpret.